# Why doesn't SchemaUpdate create this table?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, sql-server-2008-r2, fluent-nhibernate

I am using NHibernate 4 and Fluent NHibernate to map classes to the database. The database is in an SQL Server 2008 Express instance. Why on earth using `SchemaUpdate` creates all tables expect this one:

```
public class UserMap : ClassMap<UserModel>
{
    public UserMap()
    {
        this.Table("User");

        this.Id(x => x.Id)
            .GeneratedBy.Native();

        this.Map(x => x.Name)
            .Length(int.MaxValue)
            .Not.Nullable();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just found out that `SchemaUpdate` fails silently when trying to create a table named "User".

Using another name for that table (e.g. "Users") solves the problem:

```
public class UserMap : ClassMap<UserModel>
{
    public UserMap()
    {
        this.Table("Users");

        this.Id(x => x.Id)
            .GeneratedBy.Native();

        this.Map(x => x.Name)
            .Length(int.MaxValue)
            .Not.Nullable();
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe could you then try escaping table name : `this.Table("\`User\`");` (db agnostic escaping, using back tilt `\``) or `this.Table("[User]");` (SQL Server specific escaping, using angle bracket).